# Title of blog returned instead of title of post

Tags: php, xml, rss, blogs, simplepie

I'm trying to parse the RSS feed from a blogger blog, however when using the `get_title()` method it returns the title of the blog and not the title of the post. I don't know if it is a problem with the blog as I didn't create it.

If anyone wants to see the rss feed for the blog it is here:

http://fashionauctionuon.blogspot.com/atom.xml

When you use the method `get_title()` it returns "Freak Like Me Fashion Show UoN" instead of say "Vintage Pop shop".

It might be something I'm doing wrong, everything else works great!

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Post your parsing code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're using `$item->get_title()`, not `$feed->get_title()`

The latter uses the feed's title, and would cause this to occur.